# Error In "subscript out of bounds" (Hidden markov chain R code)

Tags: r

In the following code, I am trying to create a matrix that will uses  transProbs and emissionProbs of HMM(Hiden Markov Chain). Upon running the loop, the first transProbs always work, and then I get an error for emissionProbs after that.

This is the error that I get.

> Error in `hmm$emissionProbs[state, observation[1]]` : 
>     subscript out of bounds**

Here is my code:

```
install.packages('HMM')
library(HMM)

hmm=initHMM(c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S5"),c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5"), transProbs=matrix(c(0.40,0.06,0.13,0,0,0.4,0.68,0.38,0.5,1,0,0.13,0.38,0.25,0,0,0.1,0.13,0,0,0.2,0.03,0,0.25,0),5,5),emissionProbs=matrix(c(0.04,0,0,0,0.04,0.47,0.57,0.54,0.61,0.58,0.38,0.4,0.4,0.33,0.19,0.11,0.02,0.06,0.06,0.12,0,0,0,0,0.08),5,5))

a = sample(c(rep("Ta",100),rep("Tb",100),rep("Tc",100),rep("Td",100),rep("Te",100)))
b = sample(c(rep("Ta",100),rep("Tb",100),rep("Tc",100),rep("Td",100),rep("Te",100)))

observation = c(a,b)

baumWelch(hmm, observation, maxIterations=100, delta=1E-9, pseudoCount=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it might be too late but I had similar problem.

In initHMM you defined your output symbols as "T1", "T2", ... , "T5".

Then, in your observation you have "Ta", "Tb", ... , "Te".

baumWelch might be trying to match your observed symbol to possible output symbols and running out of the index, so make sure your expected output symbols match the symbols in your observation